# Typescript Implicitly or Explicitly Asserting Narrow Type Equality

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

## What I'm Trying to Do

I have two objects. One has properties that will contain values, the other has properties that contain functions that can retrieve values of the same type. They have the same keys, and the correct keyname matches the return types, to the property types. Easier to show you an example.

```
type TypeOne = 'One';
type TypeTwo = 'Two';

interface Storage {
    myString: TypeOne;
    myNumber: TypeTwo;
}

interface Fetchers {
    myString: () => TypeOne;
    myNumber: () => TypeTwo;
}
```

I would like to be able to assign values to my storage, by calling the same named function on Fetchers, like this.

```
// Imagine our instance of storage and instance of fetchers are all good to go
const setItemToStorage = (index: keyof Storage) => {
    const storedItem = storage[index]; // Type is "One" | "Two"
    const fetchedItem = fetchers[index](); // Type is "One" | "Two"
    storage[index] = fetchers[index](); // Blows up
}
```

## What's Going Wrong

Typescript gives me the following compilation error:

`Type '"One" | "Two"' is not assignable to type 'never'. Type '"One"' is not assignable to type 'never'`

I believe the reason it's doing this is straightforward. It thinks I may be trying to assign "One" to a property of type "Two", or possibly "Two" to a property of type "One". But it has enough information to infer that I am either assigning "One" to a property of type "One" OR I am assigning "Two" to a property of type "Two", because while the index is consistent, the storage/fetcher typing is consistent.

## Alternatives

I know there are a few alternatives. I can narrow the index with a switch case statement. After doing so, it will be certain that I am assigning "One" to "One". This shouldn't be necessary. It doesn't need to know what the keyname is, only that it is not changing. I'll take this approach if typescript straight up doesn't support my case.

I know I could just write each method out. `addMyStringToStorage()`, `addMyNumberToStorage()` etc.

## How do?

Can I achieve this pattern without writing code for each property name? To put it another way, how can I convince typescript that a value's type within a union remains consistent without narrowing down exactly what it is?

## Handy

[A typescript playground that elucidates the problem](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAKuEHkB20C8UDkyIYNwChRJZ4YB3AeynQ3Ir33wEslgIAnAMwEMBjaAJJsAtgGVgFdtwDm0AN74oSqMJDj2LaQC4SkbAWUqQAOQCuwgEYcdcSHQIBfRizZc+0AGIRgvABYcAZygFQ1V1TR0ACgBKagA+XUQUA2VVM0trKBj4xPt8J3xeCiQA4ChSyRkIHSEIMQkpWWpgxSNwpG1MbAwAGla08yt2HVpKDHzGIpKyzm8-QJ0vH392IPQQtuANDqjY1ASsFF7+k0HM7P3MOnGCqdLy71rhGApxSqb0SJYAEwgADx0AGsICAKJwoE83o0IHsEhslHcyhV2BBvk9msiqgBtH7-AC6uCgAHoiYkoEwggAibCUqAAHyglLolNaCOK91my1R6PQnPmqxxSF+fzxMUJJLJFMZNPpjOZrPKDWxuJFzT5KwCguFoui4tJMF8UoCvgopgANt8oFYoGAKAEAkwLGaIBN8BKABIUMhQb5UMjQQFIL1QIgQAK8DRgJEm82W628bhgbhO6BgkOGgJu-UZkPwKBIbjsdhezRQRNgYt8XxQSjsQEBAB0UAAgkL09ALBRviAoGmIFWoAmAtBStwRBBWDWmGazWWzWRuCAgtbgP5ytxhBAG1moAAhCAJ0zD8lC-5QXzcILcKCcFhMNhQM0UsppgBu3DNpjDPTns7TZENPwyxRKB3yfS1OEkKB-gPUxgFLVcjWAMc6gnYA+glf1B24JAfW8DhhBYaAzQoaQmATGce1XMdc2IAsixLDpyhjC0kAwMprRQVFURvKDEKCUdx1YbdCnZMoyHvXxbAgYxC2LCSmM+FUgRBNNISVWRYRaJQAgk5YshVWJ4Ww48MDCLZNAwLQFR0jSIC1fE1TmDUHJFMUbKtFFuEBFIEUvaAzNODJ2CsjzMVkVy8ScrkBRVHVfOUCwvJ8hVfh4c1gGswwlFXeSrhzKUmGEW17UdZ0GCUJwHCAA)

Comment: Can you please share this code on https://www.typescriptlang.org/play with the examples of what you want to achieve?

Comment: Alrighty, I've included that in an edit now, thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that's possible in TS, but I might be wrong, maybe someone smarter comes along.

In the meantime, I would combine storage and fetchers together if possible:

```
type TypeOne = 'One';
type TypeTwo = 'Two';

type Combined<A extends TypeOne = TypeOne, B extends TypeTwo = TypeTwo> = {
    myString: {
        storage: A,
        fetcher: () => A
    },
    myNumber: {
        storage: B,
        fetcher: () => B
    }
}

declare const combined: Combined;

const setItemToStorage = <T extends keyof Combined>(index: T) => {
    const storedItem = combined[index]['storage'];
    const fetchedItem = combined[index]['fetcher']();
    combined[index]['storage'] = combined[index]['fetcher']();
}
```

Not sure if that satisfies your needs tho.

Comment: This is a slightly different approach that solves what I'm specifically trying to do, which is great for me. I'll wait to see if anyone posts an answer that addresses the issues with typescript not inferring the consistent types from the consistent key.

Comment: Also, from fiddling with your solution, I don't think you need the generic A and generic B there - they don't change anything. You can just have { storage: TypeOne, fetcher: () => TypeOne } etc.

Answer (score 1):

**The Problem**

You are trying to assign a value to some dynamic key `index` in object, in your case `storage[index]`, but! the type for the `storage` does not have [indexed type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#index-types) to do so, so it evaluates to `never`.

You can check it for yourself, by adding `[key: string]: any`:

```
interface ItemStorage {
  myString: TypeOne;
  myNumber: TypeTwo;
  [key: string]: any
}
```

It compiles with indexed type.

In other words, roughly speaking, you can not use `storage[index]` semantics without indexed type, meaning you need to look for alternatives, or add an indexed type as above.

**What are the alternatives?**

Use `Map` e.g.

```
const storage: Map<keyof ItemStorage, ItemStorage[keyof ItemStorage]> = new Map([
  ['myString', 'One'],
  ['myNumber', 'Two']
]);

const setItemToStorage = (index: keyof ItemStorage) => {
  const storedItem = storage.get(index); // Type is "One" | "Two"
  const fetchedItem = fetchers[index](); // Type is "One" | "Two"
  storage.set(index, fetchers[index]()); // This should be possible
}
```

We are saying that our Map must have keys of `ItemStorage` and values of `ItemStorage`. Then, when we create a Map with data, it will type check that it corresponds to `ItemStorage` you defined early. The same type check will be applied when you are `.set()` them, it even adds you an auto-completion.

Although, it can be a little bit dirty at first glance, or overhead for such a case, so decide for yourself.

[Playground with Map](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAKuEHkB20C8UDkyIYNwChRJZ4YB3AeynQ3Ir33wEslgIAnAMwEMBjaAJJsAtgGVgFdtwDm0AN74oUYSHHsW0gFwlI2AkpUA5AK7CARh21xIdAgF9GLNlz7QAYhGC8AFhwDOUAoGqsDqSFpQABQAlNQAfDqIKPrKICbmllGxqAnWELb4Dvi8FEh+wFDlkjIQ2gCy3GAAPADWECAUnFBCEGISUrIANN0i4tWyANptHV09feMQALoJ6ChkUA1gkROKUBMYKmoaGMNYKBiLg7v7RqYW7CeYdBf4i9EExaXlUJyePv7aDxeXzsALoIKpI7hbQxeKYbAnXa3DLsGHZBK0SgYQqMEplCp+TxzGAUMYDNBRFgAEwgAA9tNNOiNemSaujArs8d8quwIFS5tRKv0agA6WTASLUunvKAAelliSgTACACJsCqoAAfKAqugqzlfCq-YF8gXoY3-UETKW0xYxXByhV5JWq9VanV63Y80WEiU24YWkF+a1IGm2mIy+WwbzKyreCjGAA2VKgFigYAofj8TDMiYgOKAA)

Answer (score -1):

Just a try, not tested, but you could define:

```js
type Fetcher = {
    [P in keyof Storage]: () => Storage[P];
};
```

In order to copy fetcher to storage, you would also probably need to write u function:

```js
function fetch2Storage<T extends keyof Storage>(index: T) {
  storage[index] = fetcher[index]()
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm actually doing that at the moment in my code, but I simplified the example. Ultimately it produces all the same typings, so there's no change in behaviour.

Comment: Sorry, posted too quickly. Please see my edit. Note that I don't have my TS editor open for the moment, so it's just a suggestion, not tested.

Comment: No worries, appreciate the help. Unfortunately that still doesn't change the result, and makes it no longer possible to type-narrow with switch-case, because the possible values of index are no longer finite.

Comment: Are you using the `extends keyof Storage`? (I edited the post twice, actually, so maybe you haven't seen it ;) ) This should narrow the index to finite possible values…